# Text field stays empty

Tags: redux-form, react-toolbox

I'm trying to integrate a React-Toolbox Input component with Redux-Form. However, the Input component remains empty when typing. I'm using https://github.com/react-toolbox/react-toolbox/issues/1293 as a guide for the integration.

```js
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import Input from 'react-toolbox/lib/input'

const renderField = ({ input, meta, ...props }) => (
  <Input
    { ...input }
    { ...props }
    error={ meta.touched && meta.error } />
)

const Form = ({ handleSubmit }) => (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Field
      name="myTextField"
      component={renderField}
      type="text"
    />
  </form>
)

Form.propTypes = {
  handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'myForm',
})(Form)
```

This is using `react-toolbox` `2.0.0-beta.12` and `redux-form` `7.2.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `input`, `meta` and another `...props` in your "functional component" `renderField`, but `renderField` props argument is named `field` and is not used anywhere.

You should change `renderField` this way:

```js
const renderField = ({ input, meta, ...props }) => (
  <Input
    { ...input }
    { ...props }
    error={ meta.touched && meta.error }
  />
);
```

**UPD**

redux-form [Basic Usage Guide](https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/docs/gettingstarted.md/#step-1-of-4-form-reducer) says:

> The redux store should know how to handle actions coming from the form components. To enable this, we need to pass the formReducer to your store. It serves for all of your form components, so you only have to pass it once.

So you should pass formReducer to your store:

```js
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  // ...your other reducers here
  // you have to pass formReducer under 'form' key,
  // for custom keys look up the docs for 'getFormState'
  form: formReducer
})

const store = createStore(rootReducer)
```

[image: Edit Redux Form - Simple Example]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, does that work for you though? I found I had forgotten to name the arguments, so I've edited my question. For me, this still doesn't work.

Comment: The redux store should know how to handle actions coming from the form components. Did you enable this by passing the formReducer to your store like in redux-form [Basic Usage Guide](https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/docs/gettingstarted.md/#step-1-of-4-form-reducer)?

You can compare your code with my live example on CodeSandbox, see the answer.

Comment: I've added the solution to the answer.